Modulating HDLC frames in GNURadio
I'm trying to modulate HDLC frames in GNURadio for transmission over an ETTUS USRP radio. I receive UDP packets via a TUNTAP interface in TUN mode and pass the resulting PDUs to a HDLC framer. If I immediately deframe the bytes and print them using the Message Debug block (Fig. 1), the output is as expected, but if I add GMSK Mod and Demod blocks between the framer and deframer (Fig. 2), the deframer no longer produces any output. I can see that the Demod block is outputting data by connecting it to a GUI Time Sink.
Why does the HDLC deframer not produce any output? I don't imagine that the CRC is failing as the data is only being modulated and demodulated, but how could I check this, or what could other reasons for this be?
Thanks!

Fig. 1 - No modulation, correct output:

Fig. 2 - Modulation, no output (incorrect):

